# Unable to boot WIndows 10 after canceling the Windows Update by turning off the PC

Tags: boot

A few days ago while I was playing League on Windows 10 it decided to force the update. It managed to stay on 20% for 3 hours in the update screen so I decided to turn off the PC as I did months ago when the same happened. Unfortunately, I couldn't get into Windows and so I was stuck in the infinite boot loop. The PC would go to GNUB after WIndows was "restoring the previous version of Windows" and would do the same thing if I chose to go to WIndows. I can't go to Safe Mode as well, I've tried turning off the PC 2/3 times on the WIndows logo to get into Safe Mode but had no luck.

Currently I'm installing the Win10 ISO file on my Ubuntu, in hope that I can go to the Troubleshoot center while booting the PC from the USB after the download is finished (WIndows should fix itself and delete the update that way). The problem is it's taking me 10hrs or so to download the file because internet is really slow here.

In the meantime, I was wondering, hypothetically, if there is a way to delete the update manually from Ubuntu and try running Windows since I just realised how easy it is to get access to the WIndows files on this system. I would really appreciate any kind of help!

BTW, I am running an old configuration - we are speaking of Athlon 5000+, GT9600, 4gb ddr2 and two HDDs (In case you thought that Windows boots too fast to access Safe Mode.)

Comment: I suggest you download the Windows 10 ISO (Bootable USB) from the Microsoft Media Creation Link. Wait for that to happen - overnight if need be. Then boot from that and try Repairing if you can (depends on the running state of the Windows 10 machine).  If not running, back up what you can and use the Reinstall function. Most likely your documents will be saved.

Comment: I used to leave my PC starting Windows all night before buying an SSD. Windows updates can be really slow. I've done what you described like a million times and never was so unlucky.